# Asymptotics of $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x-1-iy}\,\mathrm{d}x$ as $y\to0$

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Consider a real analytic, positive-valued function $f:(1,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ satisfying
\begin{equation}
f(x)\sim(x-1)^{-\alpha}\qquad(x\to1)
\end{equation}
for some $\alpha\in(0,1)$. For all $y>0$, consider the integral
\begin{equation}
I(y)=\int_1^{\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x-1-iy}\,\mathrm{d}x,
\end{equation}
supposing that $f(x)$ vanishes at $x\to\infty$ fast enough to ensure $I(y)$ to converge. As $y\to0$, numerical evidence suggests me that $I(y)$ diverges like this:
\begin{equation}
I(y)\sim y^{-\alpha}\qquad(y\to0),
\end{equation}
i.e.
\begin{equation}
\lim_{y\to0}y^\alpha I(y)\text{  is finite, }
\end{equation}
but I am currently unable to prove it, nor to find sufficient additional conditions for this to hold.

**My attempt:** for every $\epsilon>0$, we can split the integral as such:
\begin{equation}
y^\alpha I(y)=\int_1^{1+\epsilon}\frac{y^\alpha f(x)}{x-1-iy}\,\mathrm{d}x+\int_{1+\epsilon}^{\infty}\frac{y^\alpha f(x)}{x-1-iy}\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation}
When taking the limit, the second term in the right-hand side should converge to zero; as for the first term, heuristically speaking, when taking $\epsilon$ "sufficiently small" we should be able to "approximate" it by substituting $f(x)$ with $(x-1)^{-\alpha}$, and thus its asymptotic behaviour should be close to the one of the integral
\begin{equation}
\int_1^{1+\epsilon}\frac{y^\alpha (x-1)^{-\alpha}}{x-1-iy}\,\mathrm{d}x,
\end{equation}
which can be computed exactly and does converge to a finite value when $y\to0$. However, this is far from being an actual proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, that was easier than I thought. I will write down here my procedure for completeness.

Without loss of generality, set $f(x)=g(x)/(x-1)^\alpha$ for some real analytic function $g$ in $(1,\infty)$ such that $\lim_{\lambda\to1^+}g(x)\equiv g(1)$ is finite. Then
\begin{equation}
y^\alpha I(y)=\int_1^\infty\frac{g(x)}{(x-1)^\alpha}\frac{y^\alpha}{x-1+iy}\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation}
Now, performing the change of variable $x'=(x-1)/y$, we obtain
\begin{equation}
y^\alpha I(y)=\int_0^\infty\frac{g(xy+1)}{x^\alpha}\frac{1}{x+i}\,\mathrm{d}x.
\end{equation}
On the other hand, we have
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{-\alpha}}{x+i}\,\mathrm{d}x=\pi(-i)^\alpha\csc\pi\alpha,
\end{equation}
thus, by dominated convergence,
\begin{equation}
\lim_{y\to0}y^\alpha I(y)=g(1)\pi(-i)^\alpha\csc\pi\alpha.
\end{equation}